# Text rotation in PDF

Tags: pdf, floating-point, rotation, coordinates, glyph

So I have this situation:

using `pdftoxml.exe` from sourceforge.net I got text tokens and their coordinates. If the pdf file was rotated (i.e. it has a `/Rotate 90` written in its source) pdftoxml.exe swaps height and width of a given page and also x and y coordinates of any given object. That is what I understand.

I was happy with it, until I came across a pdf file which used `re` to draw thick lines. That is, for a thick line, 4 thin lines are drawn and the space is filled, like in this picture. On the left you see two thin lines (non colored), which are part of a bigger rectangle (highly zoomed in). I emptied the space inbetween which was actually filled with black, to see the lines:

[image]

Additionally, above pdf is rotated. So to get `B` upright in the end, this textmatrix was used: `0 1 -1 0 90.72 28.3705 Tm`. The thin lines were drawn like this from `83.04 27.891 0.48 0.48 re` (coordinates may vary here, but it was some re operation like that. The operation goes like `x y width height re` and `re` is for rectangle from [adobe's pdf 1.7](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) page 133). What is relevant here is the calculation `27.891 + 0.48 = 28.371` which is not rounded or altered because of floating-point issues. It is the exact value for the line's x and unfortunately, it is bigger than the hard coded `B`'s x which is `28.3705` :

```
83.52 27.891 m 92.39999999999999 27.891 l s

92.39999999999999 27.891 m 92.39999999999999 28.371 l s

92.39999999999999 28.371 m 83.52 28.371 l s

83.52 28.371 m 83.52 27.891 l s
```

The page's coordinates go like `842 x 595,2` according to PDFXChange viewer from upper left corner. Which seems natural since the page is rotated. Unrotated, it would be the lower left corner, so that ought to be ok.

---

When the text is altered with `1 0 0 1 90.72 28.3705 Tm` into its original orientation, one can see the collapsing bottom line with the line on the left:

[image]

which is what I would expect, since `B` 's y is `28.3705` and and the line's horizontal position is `28.371` (as can be seen on the second line of above code lines). So probabyly `B`'s bottom line falls beyond the `28.371` but I could not zoom that.

Now where does the gap between the line and the `B` come from in the first picture? This is important to me because I was trying to figure out which is the closest line on the left to `B` and was surprised by the two values, namely the suppsed x value of the text I get from pdftoxml.exe which is `28.3705` and the lines horizontal value `28.371`. Since I knew the line is actually far beyond the left of the `B` that could not be correct, at least not in the sense of "take x position of line, take x position of B, compare, and if the line's x is less then than `B`'s x, the line is on the left".

I can't locate the correct line with the x values. Instead I get the other line on the very left...like as if the text was falling inbetween them two.

This is the text drawing code:

```
BT
%0 7.5 -7.5 0 90.72 28.3705 Tm
0 1 -1 0 90.72 28.3705 Tm
%1 0 0 1 90.72 28.3705 Tm
/F1 1 Tf
1 Tr
q
0.01 w
(B) Tj
Q
ET
```

so, there is nothing fancy happening with the B's size or line thickness.

Can you help me figure out?

---

This is an updated picture with two `I` drawn on the same page, for the upper `I` using `0 1 -1 0 90.72 28.3705 Tm` (rotated 90 degrees mathematically), for the lower one `1 0 0 1 90.72 28.3705 Tm`. So I don't get it, how is the lower `I` rotated `+90` and ends up being the upper one?

Here is the pdf code. It is rather big, but you should be able to copy it into your file and name it sth.pdf.

[image]

[PDF Sample ( you have to actually zoom into the upper left corner real big to see the `I` )](https://docs.google.com/folder/d/0B5mSEsSR-2gPanJRQ2p6Ylg3ZVE/edit)

EDIT
I actually found some [interesting information](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96120/using-xetex-to-calculate-the-bounding-box)  about finding the glyph bounding box, but I could not yet put the pieces together.

Comment: looks to be fairly general floating point comparison and rounding problems so have retagged.

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with the numbers, though they look not nice, but that is no problem in drawing lines or circles in pdf. and also, the number `28.3705` is hard coded into the pdf's source and the number `28.371` was calculated by `27.891 + 0.48` and that is the correct answer.

Comment: Fair enough. Fwiw, here's what the PDF 1.7 spec says about floating point representation: `Real objects represent mathematical real numbers. The range and precision of numbers may be limited by the internal representations used in the computer on which the conforming reader is running`

Comment: I don't know...could be. The numbers are so small. The difference for the two pictures look to me like ~ `0.1`, taking bottom left corner of B. In above like more than `28.4` and below probably `28.3705`. Wouldn't that be too much of for a rounding issue? Maybe it is something with the rotation, but when I rotate the lower picture B in my head up, it does not jump `0.1` to the right automatically?

Comment: Could be that you're also being affected by the resolution of whatever you're using to output/display the PDF. It just can't accurately show differences that are that small?

Comment: Actually it does show the difference fwics - just why is a difference? To be fair, you're right, my viewer shows a lot but not as much as I would like. I miss exact values for a point, as it is difficult to tell from the rulers.

Comment: Concerning your double I graphic --- please post the PDF and please explain in detail what surprises you.

Comment: @mkl I included a link for you, please hava a look if you can download.

Comment: @panny I just got around to have a look at your PDF. To begin with, there are errors in your content stream, at first glance: 1. You use special graphics state operators (**q** and **Q**) inside a text object which is not allowed (cf. Figure 9, section 8.2, [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)); 2. You have an unused number 7 at the beginning of the first text object. And please explain what you would have expected to see instead.

Comment: @mkl thanks for having a look. Oh sorry, yes, the 7 was just a mistake, I'm sorry. It should be deleted. I didn't think about the state operators but thanks for the hint. I'm not really after generating pdf's, it is just a printout for human eye verification. I would have expected to see a common point - the rotation point - in both I characters, so I can get hands on a reliable horizontal coordinate for the left bounding box side of a character. Do you have any idea how to find out? The pdf reader obviously can place the text at the correct position, does it really calculate it from the font?

Comment: @danny The rotation point should be the glyph origin, shouldn't it? I enhanced my answer by an edited copy of your image indicating the common glyph origin of the I-glyphs. PdfReaders simply transform the glyphs into the user space, the glyph origin, i.e. (0, 0) in the glyph coordinate system is mapped to your (90.72, 28.3705), and the glyph is painted accordingly taking your (0, 1, -1, 0) and (1, 0, 0, 1) respectively and the font size into account

Comment: thanks mkl! This is of tremendous help. I need to think about it though, I can't figure out ad hoc how to make the calculations. will be back for this later.

Comment: @mkl Do you have any idea why the glyph origion is defined a bit more to the left than the bounding box? Does that have a special rational?

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at

[image: Glyph metrics]

> The glyph origin is the point (0, 0) in the glyph coordinate system. Tj and other text-showing operators shall position the origin of the first glyph to be painted at the origin of text space.

(shamelessly copied from [Figure 39, section 9.2.4 of ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)).

As you can see, the coordinates where the glyph is positioned, the glyph origin, is not necessarily where the actual glyph bounding box starts. This may explain the gap in your first image.

Thus, when you are *trying to figure out which is the closest line on the left to B* optically, it does not suffice to *take x position of line, take x position of B, compare, and if the line's x is less then than B's x, the line is on the left,* instead you also have to take the font data themselves into account and factor in the gap between glyph origin and glyph bounding box of the glyph represented by *B*.

For a more in-depth analysis please supply the font data.

**EDIT** concerning your double-I question... in your comment above you say you actually *expected to see a common point - the rotation point - in both I characters, so* you *can get hands on a reliable horizontal coordinate for the left bounding box side of a character.*

[image: double-I situation]

Isn't the point where the red lines cross, your rotation point? It should be the glyph origin for both Tj operations, and the I-glyphs have their origins there. Now you can measure from there on.

Comment: Thanks for this good illustration of the rotation point. Since the pdf spec says, the glyph origion is placed in the text space, this point has coordinates `(28.3705, 90.72)`. Still there is no way to get the bounding box coordinates, i.e., the gap distance?